# What behaviour would be after executing this part of C# code?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to implement the quick sort algorithm.But I have a little question when I'm creating the method quickSort and giving as params an arrayToSort and two integers high and low.Inside that method I'm calling another method partition(arrayToSort,low,high) that changes the array(swapping some elements or smth. doesn't matter),and after that I'm calling recursively the same method quickSort with the same parameter: arrayToSort,low,high (the same array that was arranged at the top as a param for the head method.).What array as a parameter would take the recursively called method quickSort? The array that was arranged at first,or the changed by the previous method one?

```
    public static void quickSort(int[] arrayToSort,int low,int high){
        int pivotLocation = 0;
        if (low < high) {
            pivotLocation = partition (arrayToSort, low, high);
            quickSort (arrayToSort, low, pivotLocation - 1);
            quickSort (arrayToSort, pivotLocation + 1, high);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After `pivotLocation = partition (arrayToSort, low, high);`, `arrayToSort` is modified(if certain conditions are met), so because recursive method calls are made after the call of `partition (arrayToSort, low, high)` then they take modified array as a paramater.
This happens at each level of recursion with the first recursive call in the function and also after that with the second.
The reason is not that a recursion is used but because of the logic in the partition method where the sorting is done by values changing places when the right conditions are met.

Your partition code is probably something like:

```
    public static int partition(int[] arrayToSort, int low, int high)
    {
        int pivot = arrayToSort[low];
        while (true)
        {

            while (arrayToSort[low] < pivot)
            {
                low++;
            }

            while (arrayToSort[high] > pivot)
            {
                high--;
            }

            if (low < high)
            {
                var temp = arrayToSort[high];
                arrayToSort[high] = arrayToSort[low];
                arrayToSort[low] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                return high;
            }
        }
    }
```

You can see in:

```
var temp = arrayToSort[high];
arrayToSort[high] = arrayToSort[low];
arrayToSort[low] = temp;
```

that the arrayToSort is modified. After the call of `partition (arrayToSort, low, high)` , the modified parameter stays modified because it is reference type different from string.